# How can I open a terminal?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

how can I open a terminal in elementary os? I could do alt+ctrl+t in ubuntu.

I have just installed this os in my system. Please help.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you :)

Answer (score 6):

windows key + t

or in the dock at bottom you will find terminal

Comment: Or on the Applications menu. Scroll until you see it or type "terminal"